# How to cross-compile from linux to android with CGO

Tags: android, cgo

I'd like to cross-compile my app from on linux for android.
executing `CGO_ENABLED=1 GOOS=android GOARCH=arm64 go build .` crashes of course, because of missing android libraries.

```
gcc_android.c:6:10: fatal error: android/log.h: No such file or directory
    6 | #include <android/log.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

what gcc should I use?

Answer (score 2):

You should use android ndk, like this:

```
CC=/home/ndk/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android21-clang CGO_ENABLED=1 GOOS=android GOARCH=arm64 go build .
```